# Kalman fiter for predicting car position using 9-axis IMU and wheel rotation/odometer for distance

Tags: c++, gps, sensors, tracking, kalman-filter

one of the applications of kalman filter is to predict car's position(in a tunnel for eg where gps signals are weak)using 9-axis IMU sensor and  car's odometer/wheel rpm - I wanted to achieve exactly same.
So i was wondering if there are already some detailed guidelines as to how to go about implementing it or better yet some form implementation which i can extend to work with my problem.
I dont want to start with scratch as much of this would have already been done, hence looking for something to continue on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start to make your kalman filter with examples in openCV library, it will allow you to print the car trajectory on a cv::Mat and then you'll be able to add your 9 parameters in the filters with the different associated weights.